# Overwide Webpage, Images Stretching?

Tags: html, css, size, width

Could anybody tell me why the following page has a horizontal scroll bar? I have tried to set the limits of any image or div to be 100% of the width of the page, but I still get the scroll bar.

Thanks so much.

http://onmywifesback.tumblr.com

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS contains the following styling for the `body { width: 100%; }`. By default a browser adds some margin, Chrome 8px, around the `<body>` tag. This makes the total larger than 100%, thus it will show a scrollbar.

You can safely remove the `width: 100%` from the `<body>` or add `body { margin: 0; }`

As a tip on how to solve these issues yourself, try opening Chrome's DevTools and simply start removing elements until the problem disappears. The element you've removed last is most likely the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width:100%` in css. That should fix it

Answer (score 0):

I have just been to the website (Safari / IE11 / Chrome, Opera & Firefox) and could not replicate your problem on my screen with a resolution of 1920 x 1080

I then checked it on my iPad Air and that never produced a scroll bar either, so it is difficult to give a precise answer, it may be the Browser you are using is an older version of IE that will need telling what to do in your .css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="[name].css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```